# See a list of all current Views in a Backbone application

Tags: backbone.js

I started an app about a year ago, and have been learning JS/BB along the way.   I don't think all of my structure has been convention, and I am now at a place where I need to strengthen my understanding.

Where I am at is that there are some views, that I a deleting or re-rendering (some via the proper BB calls *`.remove` and some by clearing the html, I know, this is bad now, but I also am having trouble locating any potential bad calls of these).  Then, later I think they are still existing.

I have tried reading about how to create views and attach them to an `$el`, whether the el is part of the parent view, and still am unsure, but I think that I can learn from this if I can find out what Views still exist.   How can I see what views exist in the BB application at a certain state?   I use Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome developer tools extension for backbone.js debugging:

https://github.com/spect88/backbone-devtools